# ubuntu 18.04 focus follows mouse before mouse pointer stops

Tags: 18.04, gnome

Is it possible to change the focus of a window in Ubuntu 18.04 (GNOME 3) so that when the mouse hovers over a window the window would be focused, but do not wait for the mouse pointer to stop for doing so?

*Tweak tool* → *Windows* → *Secondary-Click*
is only part of what I need, because it waits for mouse pointer to stop before changing the focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've managed to find it.
Using dconf-editor, set to false:
org/gnome/mutter/focus-change-on-pointer-reset